# Aggregate a dataframe in R and take column wise proportion

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, percentage

I have a **dataframe** like this:

| Year | Net | Cost | Gross |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 5637 | 6749 | 6849 |
| 2011 | 5738 | 2810 | 5749 |
| 2012 | 4829 | 5738 | 5783 |
| 2013 | 9587 | 6749 | 5739 |
| 2014 | 4638 | 6739 | 6748 |

I want column wise percerntages for each year:

| Year | Net | Cost | Gross |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | XX% | XX% | XX% |
| 2011 | XX% | XX% | XX% |
| 2012 | XX% | XX% | XX% |
| 2013 | XX% | XX% | XX% |
| 2014 | XX% | XX% | XX% |

These percentages are column wise percentages. I coded as this:

```
percent = prop.table(as.matrix(test[2:4]), margin=2)
```

But I do not get the Year column. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
     mutate(round(100 *across(2:4, proportions), 2))
```

-output

```
  Year   Net  Cost Gross
1 2010 18.53 23.45 22.19
2 2011 18.86  9.76 18.62
3 2012 15.87 19.93 18.73
4 2013 31.51 23.45 18.59
5 2014 15.24 23.41 21.86
```

---

With the OP's code, we could `cbind` with the first column

```
cbind(test[1], prop.table(as.matrix(test[2:4]), margin=2))
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(Year = 2010:2014, Net = c(5637L, 5738L, 4829L, 
9587L, 4638L), Cost = c(6749L, 2810L, 5738L, 6749L, 6739L), Gross = c(6849L, 
5749L, 5783L, 5739L, 6748L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with bind_cols:

```
percent <- test[1] %>% bind_cols(as.data.frame(prop.table(as.matrix(test[2:4]), margin=2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. If you want to keep your code as much as possible, I would suggest

```
test[2:4] <- prop.table(as.matrix(test[2:4]), margin = 2)
```